# Python 3.4.4 Limiting to 2 digits isn't working (format(self.NUMBER, '.2f'))

Tags: python, digits

I am trying to round a self.correct_answer = Smth. * Smth. 
I tried `round(self.correct_answer, 2)` and several different `format(self.correct_answer, '.2f')` type things.

Is it because of the 'self.'?

```
self.correct_answer = self.numbers1[self.number1] / self.numbers2[self.number2] 
format(self.correct_answer, '.2f')
```

Comment: `format()` and `round()` *return* their result. Numbers are immutable objects, they are not altered in-place. `format()` also produces a string object, not another number, and is intended to help you present the values, not to round.

Answer (score 0):

`format` is not in-place (like any other string-related function/method in Python). You need to reassign its return value:

`formatted = format(self.correct_answer, '.2f')`

Keep in mind  what  Martijn Pieters mentioned in the comment. `format` returns a string, not a float.